# Substituting $u=\ln$ when lower bound is $0$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, substitution

The following substitution came up in the solution set when I was practicing Diff. Geom., and it seems wrong to me:
$$\int_0^t\cos(\ln x) dx = \int_0^{\ln(t)} \cos(u)e^u du$$
When $u$ is evaluated at the lower bound, it is not defined! Additionally, the limit $\ln s\downarrow 0 = -\infty$.

Is this just very sloppy notation in the solution set, or am I missing something else?

Comment: One more bug in a textbook ! $\to +1$ for finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct:
$$x\in[0,t],\,u=\ln(x)\Rightarrow u\in(-\infty,\ln t]$$
and so:
$$\int_0^t\cos(\ln(x))dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln(t)}e^u\cos(u)du$$
you may want to split this integral up into two parts: $I=I_1+I_2$ if that is clearer:
\begin{align}I=\int_{-\infty}^0e^u\cos(u)du=\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\ln(t)}e^{(1+i)u}du=\Re\left[\frac{e^{(1+i)u}}{1+i}\right]_{-\infty}^{\ln(t)}\end{align}
\begin{align}=\Re\left(\frac{(1-i)e^{(1+i)\ln(t)}}{2}\right)=\Re\left(\frac{(1-i)t\left(\cos(\ln(t))+i\sin(\ln(t))\right)}{2}\right)\end{align}
$$=\frac t2\Re\left(\left[\cos(\ln(t))+\sin(\ln(t))\right]+i\left[\sin(\ln(t))-\cos(\ln(t))\right]\right)$$
$$=\frac t2\left[\cos(\ln(t))+\sin(\ln(t))\right]=\frac t{\sqrt{2}}\cos\left(\ln(t)-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it should read:

$$\int_0^t\cos(\ln x) dx = \int_{- \infty}^{\ln(t)} \cos(u)e^u du.$$